# Create file in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jena

I'm trying to create rdf model with Apache Jena TDB, so here is the code:

```
(def model (com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDBFactory/createModel "/rdfrepo"))
```

Which gives me following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.file.FileException: Failed to open: /rdfrepo/node2id.idn (mode=rw)
```

I have tried adding

```
:resource-paths ["shared" "resources"]
```

to `projects.clj` but didn't make any change.

I'm not very familiar with file system management in Clojure so I really need help with this one.

Comment: A path that begins with `/` is always at the root of the file system, which is a place you should not be trying to write. Will the code work without the leading `/` on the path?

Comment: Yes it works. Now I'm getting another error but that is another question. This solved my problem. Can you put this into answer so I can mark question solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get resource file with `clojure.java.io/resource`

```
(clojure.java.io/resource "css/default.css")
=>  #<URL file:/Users/yyy/xx/resources/css/default.css>
```

You don't need to add the `/` before the resource path.

You can then open the file with `io/file`:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(-> "file.png" io/resource io/file)
```

In your case you can try passing `(io/resource "rdfrepo")` to `createModel`

Answer (score 2):

A path that begins with `/` is always at the root of the file system, which is a place you should not be trying to write. Will the code work without the leading `/` on the path?